# performing authorisation/authentication between webservices

Tags: c#, asp.net

i am developing webservices.In that i want to maintain state information so that all WebMethods could be access only after Login.
I have tried but getting problem.
I am attaching my code.
Any other alternative will also be welcomed.

---

[

WebService(Namespace = "http://amSubfah.org/")]

[

WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo = WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)]

// To allow this Web Service to be called from script, using ASP.NET AJAX, uncomment the following line.

// [System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptService]

public

class Login : System.Web.Services.WebService {

Message msgObj = new Message();

BaseClass b = new BaseClass();

PasswordEncryptionDecryption pedObj = new PasswordEncryptionDecryption();

public AuthHeader Authentication=new AuthHeader ();

public Login () {

//Uncomment the following line if using designed components

//InitializeComponent();

}

[

SoapHeader("Authentication", Required = true)]

[System.Web.Services.

WebMethod(EnableSession = true)]

public string checkUserLogin(string user, string pwd)

{

DataSet dsLogin = new DataSet();

List sqlParams = new List();

SqlParameter sqlParam1 = new SqlParameter("@UserName", SqlDbType.NVarChar);

sqlParam1.Value = user;

sqlParams.Add(sqlParam1);

SqlParameter sqlParam2 = new SqlParameter("@Password", SqlDbType.NVarChar);

string pass = pedObj.encryptPassword(pwd);

sqlParam2.Value = pass;

sqlParams.Add(sqlParam2);

try

{

b.initializeDBConnection();

dsLogin = b.execSelectLoginQuery(

Query.strSelectLoginData, sqlParams);

}

catch (SqlException sqlEx)

{

string str = msgObj.msgErrorMessage + sqlEx.Message + sqlEx.StackTrace;

}

{if ((dsLogin != null) && (dsLogin.Tables[0].Rows.Count != 0))

{

Session[

"username"] = user;

string sessionId = System.Guid.NewGuid().ToString();

Authentication.sessionId = sessionId;

Authentication.Username = user;

return msgObj.msgLoginSuccess;

}

else

return msgObj .msgLoginFail ;

}

//webmethod for registration

[

SoapHeader("Authentication", Required = true)]

[System .Web .Services .

WebMethod (EnableSession =true )]

public string insertRegistrationDetails(string fName,string lName,string email,string pwd)

{

//string u = Session["username"].ToString();

//if (u == "")

//{

// //checkUserLogin(fName,pwd );

// return "Please login first";

//}

if (Authentication.Username == null || Authentication.sessionId == null)

{

return "Please Login first";

}

List sqlParams = new List();

int insert = 0;

string msg = "" ;

SqlParameter sqlParam = new SqlParameter("@FName", SqlDbType.NVarChar);

sqlParam.Value = fName;

sqlParam.Size = 50;

sqlParams.Add(sqlParam);

SqlParameter sqlParam1 = new SqlParameter("@LName", SqlDbType.NVarChar);

sqlParam1.Value = lName;

sqlParam1.Size = 50;

sqlParams.Add(sqlParam1);

SqlParameter sqlParam5 = new SqlParameter("@Email", SqlDbType.NVarChar);

sqlParam5.Value = email;

sqlParam5.Size = 50;

sqlParams.Add(sqlParam5);

SqlParameter sqlParam7 = new SqlParameter("@Password", SqlDbType.NVarChar);

sqlParam7.Value = pedObj .encryptPassword (pwd);

sqlParam7.Size = 50;

sqlParams.Add(sqlParam7);

try

{

b.initializeDBConnection();

insert = b.execByKeyParams(

Query.strInsertIntoRegistrationTable1, sqlParams);

if (insert !=0)

{

msg = msgObj .msgRecInsertedSuccess ;

}

}

catch (SqlException sqlEx)

{

string str = msgObj.msgErrorMessage + sqlEx.Message + sqlEx.StackTrace;

}

return msg;

}

public class AuthHeader : SoapHeader

{

public string Username;

public string sessionId;

}

}

Answer (score 0):

You have `EnableSession=true` set so you are part of the way there.  Each request coming in to the webservice will be establised as part of the same session as the logged in user.

Your login code should set some kind of value in session to indicate that the user has successfully logged in.  One approach is to add code to Global.asax (or create Global.asax if you don't have one) as that is executed on every request.  In there you can validate that the  values are saved in session indicating a proper login.

If the user has not logged in and is trying to call the webservice, then the code in global.asax will see that the logged in value is not saved in session, and you can re-direct them to the login page.